# Why is WSAAddressToString LPSOCKADDR parameter non-const?

Tags: winsock2

The documentation for [WSAAddressToString](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winsock2/nf-winsock2-wsaaddresstostringa) does not mention the API modifying the LPSOCKADDR lpsaAddress parameter, yet the parameter is declared as non-const.

If the API doesn't modify the parameter then the parameter should be const.
Any ideas as to why LPSOCKADDR lpsaAddress parameter is non-const?
Perhaps a typo in the API and documentation?

Comment: This is a very old function. Const-correctness was not invented until 1989, and it took several more years before it became prevalent.

Comment: Wow I could not believe it when I saw who replied. Thank you Raymond for your reply, and thank you also for your many contributions to the Win32 community.  I greatly appreciate your The Old New Thing articles.